# putting a patch into a 2d matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a patch generated by the following code:

```
t=0:2*pi;
x=cos(t)*50+100;
y=sin(t)*50+100;
f1_h=fill(x,y,'r');
```

and would like to put the output of this patch into a 2D double matrix. This so I can use it to experiment on with other code (not for displaying purposes).

So this would be something like

```
d=zeros(1000,1000);
d=d.+patchToImage(f1_h)
```

except that patchToImage does not appear to exist.

Comment: are you just looking to insert it as a subarray?

Comment: subarray is fine as that way I can use addition to put it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using `meshgrid` and then applying `inpolygon`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the parameters of inpolygon can you explain them?